# Is it possible to find the depth of an internal point of an object using stereo images (or any other method)?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have image of robot with yellow markers as shown

[image]

The yellow points shown are the markers. There are two cameras used to view placed at an offset of 90 degrees. The robot bends in between the cameras. The crude schematic of the setup can be referred.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVyDq.png

Using the two cameras I am able to get its 3d co-ordinates of the yellow markers. But, I need to find the 3d-co-oridnates of the central point of the robot as shown.

[image]

I need to find the 3d position of the red marker points which is inside the cylindrical robot. Firstly, is it even feasible? If yes, what is the method I can use to achieve this?
As a bonus, is there any literature where they find the 3d location of such internal points which I can refer to (I searched, but could not find anything similar to my ask).

I am welcome to a theoretical solution as well(as long as it assures to find the central point within a reasonable error), which I can later translate to code.

Comment: given a yellow point, the red center could be anywhere around it, on the surface of a sphere of that radius. you need to give that thing more points, or work with detecting the entire ring, and locating it in space. -- calculating poses/positions relative to other poses/positions, that's a robotics/geometry problem.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I can estimate the ring using the orange marker. But the estimation is a 2D projected estimation. The accuracy of the ring estimation also depends on what angle the robot is bending. Given these constraints, would it still be advisable to use the rings to estimate the center point? 
Or is there any way to mitigate these constraints?

Comment: Maybe it will not be precise enough, but if you assume that the curve passing through the centers is a translation away from the curve described by the yellow dots, you then "just" have to figure out where on that curve the centers are

Comment: You could estimate the translation parameters using the uppermost black oval

Comment: @BillBokeey That was exactly what I tried implementing as well. But I am not sure about the accuracy as it goes further down the pipe. It gets less and less accurate further away from the top

Comment: Do you know how the robot works internally? How and where are the forces applied? The stiffness of it? Seems like you could solve mechanically instead of geometrically

Comment: @BillBokeey The mechanics of the robot is to be validated using the position obtained from the camera, so cannot use that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have been able to extract the midpoint by fitting an ellipse to the arc visible to the camera. The centroid of the ellipse is the required midpoint.

[image: Resulting image]

There will be wrong ellipses as well, which can be ignored. The steps to extract the ellipse were:

- Extract the markers
- Binarise and skeletonise
- Fit ellipse to the arc (found a matlab function for this)
- Get the centroid of the ellipse

  ```
  hsv_img=rgb2hsv(im);
  bin=new_hsv_img(:,:,3)>marker_th; %was chosen 0.35

  %skeletonise
  skel=bwskel(bin);

  %use regionprops to get the pixelID list
  stats=regionprops(skel,'all');
  for i=1:numel(stats)
      el = fit_ellipse(stats(i).PixelList(:,1),stats(i).PixelList(:,2));
      ellipse_draw(el.a, el.b, -el.phi, el.X0_in, el.Y0_in, 'g');
  ```
- [The link for fit_ellipse function](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3215-fit_ellipse)
- [Link for ellipse_draw function](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/289-ellipse-m)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74181805/2602877

Comment: Glad that you found a solution to the problem, but this seems particularly only useful for you and very close to my solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the actual dimensions, or at least, shape (e.g. perfect circle) of the white bands, then yes, it is feasible and possible.

You need to do the following steps, which are *quite* non trivial to do, and I won't do them here:

0. Optional but **extremely** suggested: calibrate your camera, and
   undistort it.
1. find the equation of the projection of a 3D circle into a 2D camera, for any given rotation. You can simplify this by assuming the white line will be completely horizontal. You want some function that takes the parameters that make a circle and a rotation.
2. Find all white bands in the image, segment them, and make them horizontal (rotate them)
3. Fit points in the corrected white circle to the equation in (1). That should give you the parameters of the circle in 3d (radious, angle), if you wrote the equation right.
4. Now that you have an analytic equation of the actual circle (equation from 1 with parameters from 3), you can map any point from this circle (e.g. its center) to the image location. Remember to uncorrect for the rotations in step 2.

This requires understanding of curve fitting, some geometric analytical maths, and decent code skills. Not trivial, but this will provide a solution that is highly accurate.

For an inaccurate solution:

1. Find end points of white circles
2. Make line connecting endpoints
3. Chose center as mid point of this line.

This will be inaccurate because: choosing end points will have more error than fitting an equation with all points, ignores cone shape of view of the camera, ignores geometry.

But it may be good enough for what you want.

Comment: But your method is assuming that the circles when projected to 2d are still circles, which is not the case. Can you please elaborate this first step.
Also, the white strips cannot be treated as a line, I have shown a simple case, but for more complicated cases, it has to be treated as a curve.

Comment: @ssuraj no, of course I don't assume that, which is the entire point of the first step, indeed. If you take a circle in 3D, it has an equation. its projection in 2D, in the camera, it has a different equation. Its the equation of a *projected circle*, not an equation of a *circle*. But you can parametrize it with the parameters of what makes it a circle+its rotation w.r.t. the camera. If you don't understand this, you got some maths reading to do, explaining it further requires explaining mathematics, which is quite off topic here as it would lead to really long answer.

Comment: What you are asking is basically a solution to a decently complex engineering task, not a programming question. I can't write 500 lines of MATLAB for you, no one can or will (for free). The best you can get is guidelines on how to code your algorithm.

Comment: I am neither expecting nor asking anyone to give me the code, I am only requesting a theoretical explanation, or pointers to for places(or rather keywords to search) which explain the theory behind this. Regarding your comment " But you can parametrize it with the parameters of what makes it a circle+its rotation w.r.t. the camera". Can you let me know what I need to search to find more about this. 

Back to your answer, I think there was a misunderstanding. I don't get the need to assume the white lines as horizontal. Why is that necessary to get the parameterised projection.

Comment: @ssuraj There is not much to search, but just understanding of geometry and equations, I don't know what to suggest.  horizontal lines: this is just a trick to make step 1 simpler. If you assume they are horizontal, you need 1 angle to describe the rotation of the projected circle, if you don't, you need 2. Basic 3D rotation geometry. Making them horizontal is trivial, with a simple rotation. You can instead ignore this, and make the equation on step 1 take 2 rotation angles. Its the same really

Comment: re: Stereographic projection may be the keyword to look for for step 1.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think I understand the intent behind the projection step now. I think your answer could work for my case. But, I'll leave the question open for the day and accept it tomorrow, to see if there are any other possible methods.

Comment: Note for accurate step 1, your projection is conical, cameras can be modeled by a pinhole, light is a cone, not just a 3D-2D projection of parallel lines, as one tends to do in stereographic projection.