# How to perform matching of markers from two images which are taken from different perspective?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a markered robot with circular markers and two images from different perspective as shown: (Circular white rings are the markers)
[image: image from cam1]
[image: image from camer2]

I want to match the markers in the two images, by matching I mean the bottommost marker of 1st image should be treated as correspondence point of bottom most marker of 2nd image and so on.
The finger-like robot given in the image can bend in any direction given in space (can also bend in a U-like manner).
If it helps, the camera geometry is fixed and known beforehand.

I am lost, as simple correspondence algorithm would not work, since the perspectives are very different.  How should I go about matching the two images?

Comment: context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581503/is-it-possible-to-find-the-depth-of-an-internal-point-of-an-object-using-stereo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471793/how-to-extract-the-white-rings-in-the-given-image

Comment: Well, if you know where the circles are in 3D, then you can easily sort them from bottom to top. Do that in both images, and the first circle in one is the first circle in the other.

Comment: @Adriaan I am not asking you to write the whole code or even come up with your own method for that matter. What I want to know is if there is existing algorithm which can do this which I might not be aware of

Comment: @AnderBiguri, that was my immediate answer as well. But it won't work for the case where robot bends in a U-like manner

Comment: The only thing you won't know if you matched them in order or in reverse. But, you literally describe a situation where you don't have enough information to resolve it. The answer is: you don't have enough information. Either you know (somehow) which circle is number 1, and you can solve it, or you don't, and you can't. How to know which one is first? that depends on contraint on your experiment. It could be that the circle at the base its always near the same place, or it could be you can put a sticker on it. We don't know.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I was hoping any matching algorithm like SIFT or optical flow ones would come to the rescue. But it would seem not, I guess I will have to add unique marker for the base

Comment: You can't just throw words and hope they work. Optical flow will work if you have a sufficiently fast frame-rate video, yes (with some error). SIFT detects features of unique objects. Your rings are not unique.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I was just giving examples to convey what I mean by matching algorithms, I dont mean to say the exact ones would help me, there would be no point in asking the question for other algorithms otherwise. It would seem that simplifying and constraining the experiment makes the most sense

Comment: Can this arm bent like a helix?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't have matching points but matching curves. You might try to fit ellipses on the rings and take the ellipse centers for points to be matched.

This is an approximation, as the center of a circle does not exactly project as the center of the ellipse, but I don't think that this will be the major source of error: as you only see half circles, the fitting will not be that accurate.

If all nine circles remain visible and are ordered vertically, the matching of the centers is trivial. If they are not ordered but don't form a loop, you can probably start from the lowest and follow the chain of nearest neighbors.

[image]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581503/is-it-possible-to-find-the-depth-of-an-internal-point-of-an-object-using-stereo/74179926#74179926

Answer (score 0):

You can start like this:

- You know the position of the mounting point on the base panel for each perspective.
- You know the positions of the white rings for each perspective as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471793/how-to-extract-the-white-rings-in-the-given-image).
- You can derive the direction of the arm at each ring by its tilt.

So you can easily determine the sequence of the positions starting with the mounting point stepping from ring to ring even if the arm is bent. With this you can match the rings from both images. If you have any situation where this fails, please add an according example to your question!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have decided to use an assumption to restrict the robot movement. In essence, it does the same thing you have described, but ensures correctness under those contraints